# How to remove a tailgate strut that do not have a c-clip

Tags: honda, body

I have a 2006 Honda Odyssey (Japanese Imported). I am located in New Zealand.

Normally you would remove the strut by loosening the c-clip and easily snap the strut off.

But my struts do not have c-clips. What would be the best way to remove them, so that I can replace them with new ones?

[image: Top of Strut]

[image: Bototm of strut]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the official Honda dealer in New Zealand. They confirmed that I need to replace the entire assembly, rather than just the arm alone. They are not the "pop out" variety. The cost is NZD305 EACH, rather expensive.

I contacted a local mechanic who said the same thing: need to replace whole assembly. He got a second hand one for NZD92, plus NZD28 labour. He assured me the second hand one is in good condition and should last a couple of years. I could have saved the labour cost the next time.

Note: Currently 1 NZD = 0.79 USD, or 0.49 UK pound

My car is the 2006 Honda Odyssey (Japanese version), model DBA-RB1. The strut assembly is made by Showa. I've included a few pictures of the old part that's been taken out:
[image: Bottom End]
[image: Top End]
[image: The whole thing]
[image: Label]

Comment: A note to non-New Zealanders. Most cars on our roads are imported second hand from Japan. So they are Japanese versions with Japanese specs. - different from American or British specs.

Comment: +1 ... Good find and good information! What a PITB! I would have had no clue they would be different in Japan than here in the States. I've always been a firm believer in not engineering something twice, but this breaks all bounds. Maybe we re-engineered it, lol. I wouldn't doubt it. Don't forget to mark this as *your* answer!

Comment: I think Hondas are assembled in different countries, when each country would have their own set of part suppliers - that is where the difference come in.

Comment: I think: Japanese people tends to buy brand new cars, and export them to other 'poorer' countries when they get to about 5 or 6 years old. Therefore there is no incentive to make their cars 'maintenance friendly'.

Comment: That last sounds reasonable. I understand they cannot fix them once wrecked, either, which I believe is the reason we can pick up STi engine/transmission combos with 40k miles on them for relatively cheap. Now I just need to buy that Factory Five 818 kit and I'll be wailing!

Answer (score 5):

They simply pop off. Gently pry them off, the spring holding it on the ball is internal.

**EDIT:** (Adding some descriptive pics for Larry)

Place a large flat tip screwdriver where the red arrow is at.

[image]

In the image below, the green flat piece is the screwdriver. Place one side of it at the base of the post. Place the other at on the rod. Twist it as shown to pop the rod off of the stud. This gives you a sturdy place to pry from and a place for good leverage.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific technique in prying them off? Would it help if I saw the arm off first, and then lever the arm off?

Comment: I used a reasonable amount of force to try to pry them off, with no luck. I suspect these are designed in such a way that you need to replace the entire assembly, rather than just the arms alone.

Comment: @dmc I just use a pry bar you can twist them a little, sometimes that help. Never had to do anything else. Pry between the strut and the nut so you don't risk damaging the body work.

Comment: @dmc ... I added some descriptive pics for Larry ... I hope he doesn't mind.

Comment: @Paulster2 nice! Thanks, and a nice answer for you!

Comment: I did try using a pry bar about a foot long - no luck. Any more force, I will dent the panel...

Answer (score 1):

If they really are 'stuck on': Using a Dremal or other mini disc cutter, cut into the ball section of the strut until it will pry off easily. A regular event for some vehicles. Do not lever too hard with the gas strut or you will bend the vehicles bodywork.

Comment: Using a Dremal is a little bit beyond my level of skill. I might have to take the car to a mechanic.

Comment: I can confirm they are the 'stuck on' variety :(